# How to convert IObservable<T> to list in RX with CancellationToken support

Tags: .net, .net-4.5, system.reactive, cancellation-token

I have a method returning an `IObservable<long>` that I call from an `async` method. I want to convert this into a normal `List<long>`, but to have that operation be cancelled if my `CancellationToken` is signaled.

I would like to do something like this:

```
List<long> result = await Foo().ToList(myCancellationToken);
```

What is the correct (and simplest) way to accomplish this? The `ToList()` extension method of `IObservable<T>` returns an `IObservable<List<T>>` and does not take a `CancellationToken` parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var list = await Foo().ToList().ToTask(cancellationToken);
```

This has the advantage of cancelling immediately if the token is cancelled (the other Answer will not cancel until the next time the `Foo` observable produces a value).

Comment: Just what I was afraid ofvwith the other answer. This seems to do the trick nicely. Thanks!

Comment: I added an extension method ``TakeWhile(CancellationToken t)`` on my answer to make sure completion occurs early rather than on the next event. It might be more useful in some situations. However the above answer is ``more`` correct than my original attempt before editing.

Comment: I would definitely prefer using the built in Rx Extension methods (this answer) than creating new ones (the other answer). If you are looking for a "more composable" solution then still, I would favour the `CancellationDisposable` type and further built in types.

Comment: And if you need to work with a `CancellationToken` that you've been given (and cannot use `CancellationDisposable`), then it is easy to write a `AsObservable()` extension method for `CancellationToken` so you can still use the regular Rx methods: `Foo().TakeUntil(token.AsObservable())...`

Answer (score 4):

Use TakeWhile to terminate the list.

```
CancellationToken MyToken = ...
var list = await Foo().TakeWhile(v=>!MyToken.IsCancellationRequested).ToList();
```

If you are worried about the subscription only cancelling when the next item is provided you can have this extensions method.

```
public static IObservable<T> 
TakeWhile<T>
    ( this IObservable<T> This
    , CancellationToken t 
    )
{
    var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(t);
    return Observable.Create<T>(( IObserver<T> observer ) => 
       { 
           This.Subscribe(observer, cts.Token);
           return Disposable.Create(() => cts.Cancel());
    });
}
```

and write

```
CancellationToken MyToken = ...
var list = await Foo().TakeWhile(MyToken.IsCancellationRequested).ToList();
```

Using TakeWhile with a cancellation token is more composable than ToTask which just returns the last element.

Comment: Looks nice, except, shouldn't the example call to the extension method be `...TakeWhile(MyToken)`? And of course, this is more general than the above solution, but if I do `.ToList()` anyway, that always returns an `IObservable` with only a single element, doesn't it?

Comment: Also, the name `TakeWhile` seems a bit misleading here, since it takes while the cancellation token is *not* canceled, but otherwise it seems like a good solution. (I still have a lot to learn on RX apparently :)